# Get the window reference from a form with a target "_blank"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with its target attribute set to "_blank".
The question is how can I (if it's possible) get the reference to the newly opened window?
The from posts some stuff so stopping the submit event propagation and opening a new window manually doesn't seem like a good option.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569776/obtain-reference-to-blank-target-window-on-form-submit) asks the same thing, however the action URL is not a page that I can control, and the answer can't help me.

Comment: `not a page that I can control` => different domain? Sounds like you'll run into the [**Same-origin Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Different domain alright, but I just want to catch the closing of this window, if possible, so no additional scripts are required from the other side.

Comment: The only way I can see this working is by opening a page on your domain which forwards the url, get and post into another (hidden) form, that auto-submits with target of a full-page `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the submit action is on another domain, the answer is no - you can't.

I ended up using cookies(after submitting, the window is redirected to an URL from the same domain as the form). You can set a cookie in another tab/window and read it in the current one without refreshing.